# How to configure an ASP.NET MVC application with Test and Release-Version strategy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I have no clue how to configure my ASP.NET MVC3 Application to work in at least two different buildversions.

What I would like to achive is a release version that's used by my customers with an database that holds their realtime data. Further more there should be at least one additional release version for testing purposes, connected to another database using test data.

Environment:
ASP.NET MVC 3
Entity Framework 4
VisualStudio 2010 Pro
MSSQL Server 2008
IIS7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start a MVC3 project you should already have 2 build web.config files: debug and release. In these files you will define your database connection. Now you can create your own build profiles through the "Configuration Manager" for developer, test, accept and release environments.